# UITextAttributeFont causes NSInvalidArgumentException on Device but not in Simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uinavigationbar

I am customizing the `UINavigationBar` of an iOS app under iOS 6. Thus, I am using the `setTitleTextAttributes` to do so.

However the specific setting

```
NSDictionary *attribute = @{UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bernard MT Condensed" size:21.0]};
```

causes the app to crash on a device, but *not* in the Simulator, with the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: 
attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5499925/746968) which seems to be of the same kind, but both my device *and* my simulator are set to the *exact* same regional settings (language, region format).

A fact worth noting is that the regional settings are set to American English in both environments, but I am showing text in a Danish regional format with danish special characters, however, it *does* work on the simulator, as noted.

Comment: The font you are trying to use is probably not on actual iOS devices.

Comment: [iOS 6 Font List](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5484?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: Correct, however, it is part of my resources and added to `Fonts provided by application`. As I mentioned it works *perfectly* in the Simulator with font and everything.

Comment: Many things work in the simulator that don't work on a real device so that does't mean much. A device is case sensitive, the simulator is not. Verify your font references in Info.plist truly match the filenames of the font files.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me! The font file name was "BERNHC.TTF" and the Info.plist stated "BERNHC.ttf". I had no idea there was difference in case sensitivity on the two environments. If you provide this as an answer I'll mark it right away!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font you are using is a custom font which requires font files to be added to the app's resources and an entry in the Info.plist.

Filename case matters on real devices, but not the simulator. You need to make sure that the entry in the Info.plist matches the real filename (including case) of the actual font files.

Side note for those that think using the Simulator is enough - This is one of the many reasons that testing on a real device is critical.